# Is hive supported for Java 9?

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

Whenever I try to load hive shell, it shows this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliSessionState.<init>(CliSessionState.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:708)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:543)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

I have java 9 and hadoop 2.7.3.

How can I overcome this error?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you can assume any version released before Java 9 probably need updating. I would try hadoop 2.7.5 http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html

Comment: The latest version 3.0.0 doesn't mention Java 9 and only just migrated off Java 7 http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.0/index.html so I would try Java 8.

Comment: Now what should I do if I have java 9 in my system?

Comment: Install Java 8 and use that.

Answer (score 3):

No.  Java 9 support is still in development.  Refer to the following JIRAs if you want to track progress:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-11123 - Uber-JIRA: Hadoop on Java 9
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-17632 - Build Hive with JDK9

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple versions of Java installed on a given system.

With your listeners versions, you'll need to downgrade.

You can edit the `hadoop-env.sh` file in your Hadoop home directory to relocate `JAVA_HOME`