# Unable to start Hadoop (3.1.0) in Pseudomode on Ubuntu (16.04)

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, namenode

I am trying to follow the Getting Started guide from the Hadoop Apache website, in particular from the Pseudo distributed configuration,
[Getting started guide from Apache Hadoop 3.1.0](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Pseudo-Distributed_Operation)

but I am unable to start the Hadoop Name- and Data Nodes. Can anyone help advise ? even if its things I can run to try to debug/investigate further.

At the end of the logs I see an Error message (not sure if its important or a red-herring).

```
    2018-04-18 14:15:40,003 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* Network topology has 0 racks and 0 datanodes

    2018-04-18 14:15:40,006 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* UnderReplicatedBlocks has 0 blocks

    2018-04-18 14:15:40,014 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: Total number of blocks            = 0

    2018-04-18 14:15:40,014 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: Number of invalid blocks          = 0

    2018-04-18 14:15:40,014 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: Number of under-replicated blocks = 0

    2018-04-18 14:15:40,014 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: Number of  over-replicated blocks = 0

    2018-04-18 14:15:40,014 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: Number of blocks being written    = 0

    2018-04-18 14:15:40,014 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* Replication Queue initialization scan for invalid, over- and under-replicated blocks completed in 11 msec

    2018-04-18 14:15:40,028 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting

    2018-04-18 14:15:40,028 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 9000: starting

    2018-04-18 14:15:40,029 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: NameNode RPC up at: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000

    2018-04-18 14:15:40,031 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Starting services required for active state

    2018-04-18 14:15:40,031 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory: Initializing quota with 4 thread(s)

    2018-04-18 14:15:40,033 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory: Quota initialization completed in 2 milliseconds name space=1 storage space=0 storage types=RAM_DISK=0, SSD=0, DISK=0, ARCHIVE=0, PROVIDED=0 2018-04-18 14:15:40,037 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.CacheReplicationMonitor: Starting CacheReplicationMonitor with interval 30000 milliseconds

> 2018-04-18 14:15:40,232 ERROR
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15:
> SIGTERM
> 
> 2018-04-18 14:15:40,236 ERROR
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: RECEIVED SIGNAL 1:
> SIGHUP
> 
> 2018-04-18 14:15:40,236 INFO
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
> /************************************************************
> SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at c0315/127.0.1.1
```

I have confirmed, that I can `ssh localhost` without a password prompt. I have also run the following steps from the above mentioned Apache Getting Started guide,

1. $ bin/hdfs namenode -format
2. $ sbin/start-dfs.sh

But I cant run step 3. to browse the location at http://localhost:9870/. When I run >jsp from the terminal prompt I just get returned,

> 14900 Jps

I was expecting a list of my nodes.

I will attach the full logs.

**Can anyone help even with ways to debug this please ?**

Java Version,
$ java --version

```
java 9.0.4 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11) 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

EDIT1 : I have repeated the steps with Java8 as well and get the same error message.

EDIT2: Following the comment suggestions below I have checked that I am definitely pointing at Java8 now and I have also commented out the localhost setting for `127.0.0.0` from the `/etc/hosts` file

[image: commented-out-localhosts]

[image: java-version]

[image: hadoop-env]

Ubuntu version,

$ lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: neon
Description: KDE neon User Edition 5.12
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial
```

I have tried running the commands, `bin/hdfs version`

```
Hadoop 3.1.0 
Source code repository https://github.com/apache/hadoop -r 16b70619a24cdcf5d3b0fcf4b58ca77238ccbe6d 
Compiled by centos on 2018-03-30T00:00Z 
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0 
From source with checksum 14182d20c972b3e2105580a1ad6990 
This command was run using /home/steelydan.com/roycecollige/Apps/hadoop-3.1.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.1.0.jar
```

when I try `bin/hdfs groups` it doesnt return but gives me,

```
018-04-18 15:33:34,590 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

when I try, `$ bin/hdfs lsSnapshottableDir`

```
lsSnapshottableDir: Call From c0315/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

when I try, `$ bin/hdfs classpath`

```
/home/steelydan.com/roycecoolige/Apps/hadoop-3.1.0/etc/hadoop:/home/steelydan.com/roycecoolige/Apps/hadoop-3.1.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/:/home/steelydan.com/roycecoolige/Apps/hadoop-3.1.0/share/hadoop/common/:/home/steelydan.com/roycecoolige/Apps/hadoop-3.1.0/share/hadoop/hdfs:/home/steelydan.com/roycecoolige/Apps/hadoop-3.1.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/:/home/steelydan.com/roycecoolige/Apps/hadoop-3.1.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/:/home/steelydan.com/roycecoolige/Apps/hadoop-3.1.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/:/home/steelydan.com/roycecoolige/Apps/hadoop-3.1.0/share/hadoop/yarn:/home/steelydan.com/roycecoolige/Apps/hadoop-3.1.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/:/home/steelydan.com/roycecoolige/Apps/hadoop-3.1.0/share/hadoop/yarn/*
```

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You need to remove `127.0.1.1` from your /etc/hosts files, and ideally don't use localhost for any services

Comment: Also, Hadoop does not support Java 9. Please downgrade Java

Comment: +1.  Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48113847/is-hive-supported-for-java-9 in particular https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-11123 for status of Java 9 for Hadoop.

Comment: thanks for the comments. I have installed Java8 but I forgot to update my `hadoop-env.sh` so re-running I was probably still referencing Java9. I will try tomorrow when I get into work. Thanks again.

Comment: ok - I can confirm that I am pointing at Java8 but I still get the same messages (see EDIT2). 
Does anyone know what this error message relates to or is it a red herring ? 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15:
> SIGTERM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find out the reason why pseudo distributed mode HDFS fails on KDE neon.
It is caused by `40_kde_neon_allyourprocessarebelongtous.conf`.

```
❯ cat /usr/lib/systemd/logind.conf.d/40_kde_neon_allyourprocessarebelongtous.conf
# SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0-only OR LicenseRef-KDE-Accepted-GPL
# SPDX-FileCopyrightText: 2016 Harald Sitter <sitter@kde.org>

[Login]
KillUserProcesses=1
```

Due to this file, `nohup` or `disown` mechanism doesn't work in KDE neon.

- https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=369490

If you comment it out, pseudo distributed mode HDFS will work.

Answer (score 1):

I have not been able to figure out (I just tried again since I miss NEON so much) but even though :9000 is not in use, the OS sends a SIGTERM in my case too.

The only way I have found to solve this was to go back to stock Ubuntu, sadly.